# How do I cycle through REQUEST and use dynamic variable naming? PHP ! :)

Tags: php, forms, request

I have a form that submits details of multiple people i.e in the $_REQUEST I get :

```
title1 = Mr, 
first_name1 = 'Whatever', 
surname1 = 'Whatever', 

title2 = Mr, 
first_name2 = 'Whatever', 
surname2 = 'Whatever'
```

There's obviously more but this explains the situation. There could be ten people being submitted and therefore it would go up to title10, first_name10, surname10...

I have been trying to use:

```
for ($x = 1; $x < 4; $x++) {

    $a = new applicant();
    $a->title       = $_REQUEST['title'+$x];
    $a->first_name      = $_REQUEST['first_name'+$x];
    $a->surname         = $_REQUEST['surname'+$x];
    $a->Save();
}
```

However it appears that you cannot do this +$x bit. I know there is a way around it since I remember doing this ages ago yet I don't have my code at work :/

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP uses `.` for concatenating strings, and `+` for adding numbers; this is different from some other languages which use `+` for both. Possibly confusing, but unlikely to change.

`'title' + $x` will try to add the parts as if they were numbers, casting if necessary.

`'title' . $x` should do what you seem to be looking for.

Read also: [The Fine Manual](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation in PHP uses the operator `.` not `+`. For example: `$_REQUEST['title' . $x];`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same attribute name in your HTML form for mulitple inputs like so:

```
<input name="title[]" />
...
<input name="title[]" />
```

Which when submitted to the PHP script will be available in the GET/POST as an array already.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this:

```
$a = "first part";
$b = "second part";

$c = ${$a.$b};
```

or something like

```
$c = $_REQUEST[${$a.$b}];
```

Anyway, you got the idea.